# Fastest implementation of priority_queue in C++?

Tags: c++, performance, queue, priority-queue

I stumbled upon custom implementations of hash tables, which are faster than `std::unordered_map` for say, int type. (For example `ska::flat_hash_map`)

For my use case, I don't need to optimize memory, the only parameter I want to be optimized is the speed. I want the execution speed to be as fast as possible. The primary operations I am concerned about are push and pop.

What are the fastest state-of-the-art implementations focusing on speed for priority_queue? (Note: I am not interested in concurrency, I am running a single-threaded program)

Comment: Are you asking for libraries to use or just asking what is way to implement them where they will be as fast as possible?

Comment: A circular buffer can be faster than the standard queue, but be careful. premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: @NathanOliver I am asking for libraries to use.

Comment: @AhmedAEK I am looking to benchmark and compare with their std:: counterparts

Comment: My vote is to use an array based circular queue.  The circular part reduces the amount of copying.  Use indices, not pointers; thus you can use the `%` operator.

Comment: I have edited the question, can it be reopened?

Comment: @ztart14578 It still seems like you are asking for a recommendation and that is off-topic here.

Comment: We do not do library request here.  There is https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ where you could ask.

Comment: Side note: Fastest is a sucker bet. 1) As you get down into the nitty-gritty details, what's fastest is a moving target heavily influenced by the data and the hardware. 2) No one pays for fastest. They pay for fast enough. Time spent chasing fastest after you've already met the requirements is time you could have spent with family and friends or on solving another problem.

Comment: Whatever datastructure you choose, do not forget to profile that datastructure on your data. There is NO fastest datastructure in general, because it also depends on your hardware (number of caches, CPU pipelining and branch prediction).

Comment: @user4581301 Haha I great timing and similar thoughts.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Needed to be said, so someone was going to.

Comment: @user4581301 Yup :)